# Recursive edge search

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will take a list of points visited along an edge, and a list of unvisited edges (made up of pairs of points) which make up the rest of the object and search through them for a path that completes the edge (that is, connects the start to the end). I currently have:

```
public static int PolygonSearch(Point start, Point end, List<Point> visitedPoints, List<Point[]> unvisitedEdges)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = unvisitedEdges.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        Point[] line = unvisitedEdges[i];
        if (((Equal(line[0], start) && Equal(line[1], end)) 
            || (Equal(line[1], start) && Equal(line[0], end))) 
            && visitedPoints.Count > 2)
        {
            return count + 1;
        }
        else if (Equal(start, line[0]))
        {
            unvisitedEdges.RemoveAt(i);
            count += PolygonSearch(line[1], end, visitedPoints, unvisitedEdges);
        }
        else if (Equal(start, line[1]))
        {
            unvisitedEdges.RemoveAt(i);
            count += PolygonSearch(line[0], end, visitedPoints, unvisitedEdges);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

(start and end being the current start and end points of the line)

The obvious problem here is the removal, which messes up the outer loops, but I'm not sure how to correct for it, I tried creating a new list each time but that didn't work (I've not even implemented a way to return the path yet, just to count the valid ones).

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume something else should stand instead of second `else if (Equal(start, line[0]))`.

Comment: I should yearh, noticed that just after posting.

Comment: It would be nice if you could spare a minute to edit the question and fix the errors.

Comment: I got called away, sorry. It's updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid removing an object, you can set it as 'removed', then ignore it if it is so set.

The following uses a flag called `Visited`. If it is 'removed', `Visited` is set to true.

I haven't tested this obviously, but it should give you a general idea of what to do:

```
public struct Edge
{
    public Edge()
    {
        this.Visited = false;
    }

    public Point[] Points;
    public bool Visited;
}

public static int PolygonSearch(Point start, Point end, List<Point> visitedPoints, List<Edge> unvisitedEdges)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = unvisitedEdges.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        Edge line = unvisitedEdges[i];
        if (((Equal(line.Points[0], start) && Equal(line.Points[1], end)) 
            || (Equal(line.Points[1], start) && Equal(line.Points[0], end))) 
            && visitedPoints.Count > 2
            && line.Visited == false)
        {
            return count + 1;
        }
        else if (Equal(start, line[0]))
        {
            unvisitedEdges[i].Visited = true;
            count += PolygonSearch(line.Points[1], end, visitedPoints, unvisitedEdges);
        }
        else if (Equal(start, line[0]))
        {
            unvisitedEdges[i].Visited = true;
            count += PolygonSearch(line.Points[1], end, visitedPoints, unvisitedEdges);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```